# How can I layout images side by side to allow comparison?

Tags: graphics

I am very very new to TeX/LaTeX, I am writing my first document. So far, I love the way it shows everything. The learning curve is steep though.

I have images that needs to be compared, so they must be close to each other. How can I achieve that?

In the image below, you can see an example of what I want (I know it is ugly, that is why I am using LaTeX ;) ). I used subfig package, but it's main purpose looks like to caption subfigures. I do not want to caption them separately, it would lead to information duplication. It does not need to be exactly like in the image, I am open to suggestions.

[image]

Comment: You will get better result if the images are vertically centered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you simply want to reproduce a similar formatting, you can use the [`tabular`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) environment to put the pictures in a table.  This would look something like:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c}
  & clown & goldhill256 & lighthouse \\ \hline
  Sobel & \includegraphics{image1} & \includegraphics{image2} & \includegraphics{image3} \\ \hline
  Sobel w/thresholding & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
  Sobel w/thresholding \& thinning & ... & ... & ...
\end{tabular}
```

It appears as if this table is going to span the width of the page, however, so you may be better off using the [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{p{1.5cm}|X|X|X}
  & clown & goldhill256 & lighthouse \\ \hline
  Sobel & \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{image1} & \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{image2} & \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{image3} \\ \hline
  Sobel w/thresholding & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
  Sobel w/thresholding \& thinning & ... & ... & ...
\end{tabularx}
```

That should...

1. cause the table to span the entire width of the page;
2. typeset the leftmost column in a 1.5cm wide parbox (which will allow for line breaks); and
3. auto-size the picture columns such that they are all the same width and take up the extra room in the page.

Comment: I get a "Missing number, treated as zero." error at the first line. Sorry I still don't know how to evaluate error messages properly. I think it needs another argument before p.

Comment: Sorry about that; I added the missing text to the `tabularx` code.  (I wrote it from memory and I just forgot the "`{\hsize}`" part.)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use subfigures. See the tutorial below for an example:

http://www.andy-roberts.net/misc/latex/latextutorial6.html